# $ajax call is pending during download file at chrome/safari not in IE/firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, asynchronous

I am downloading 1mb file with ajax calls and checking the download time.
Here is the code

```
var start = new Date();
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $.ajax ({
        url: 'https://www.example.com/dummyFile1024',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "application/octet-stream",
        cache: false,
        async: false,    
        success : function()
        {
             var asd=(new Date() - start)
             alert(asd) 

        },    
        error : function(jqxhr, status, ex) {}   
    })
})
```

At chrome and safari it is waiting to load complete file not in IE and firefox. when I check with developer tools network. At firefox after get http/1.1 200 connection established and shows to connection time to server. in chrome developer tools it is pending after connection established and load complete file and alert the value. How can I make this works for all browsers? 
P.S. I have tried with another file type jpeg and same thing happened. firefox and ie showed just connection time to server chrome and safari waited until whole picture loaded.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [you can't use synchronous requests on crossDomain communication](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> "Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support
> synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily
> lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active."

It's possible that IE/firefox are ignoring the "async: false" parameter.

Second, use the "complete" function to get all browsers to execute the code when the DL finishes.